# convert resnet implementation from caffe to tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I want to implement resnet 50 from scratch
it is implemented in caffe by author of original paper,but i want tensorflow implementation
due to this repository :https://github.com/KaimingHe/deep-residual-networks
and therefor this image : http://ethereon.github.io/netscope/#/gist/db945b393d40bfa26006
I know every equivalent (in tensorflow),but i dont lknow the meaning of scale in place,after batch normalization,can you explain me the meaning and also "use globale state " parameter in batchnorm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An "in-place" layer in caffe simply hints caffe to save memory: instead of allocating memory for both input and output of the net, "in-place" layer overrides the input with the output of the layer.
2. Using global state in `"BatchNorm"` layer means using the mean/std computed during training and **not** updating these values any further. This is the "deployment" state of BN layer.

Comment: thanks  for reply 
but in implementation of resnet in github,they said,batchnorm params should be updated,specially the implementation that converted caffe model to tensorflow,so what should I do ?
this is converted implementation:
(https://github.com/chenxi116/TF-resnet)

Comment: @sh.kh you should distinguish between "deploy"/"val" net - when the weights are fixed after training, and "train" net - where the weights (and batch-norm params) are constantly updated. I suppose your converted net should be able to operate in these two modes.

Comment: @sh.kh yes, you update batch norm params during training

Comment: so in train mode,the batchnorm params (mean and variance) should be updated and in eval mode they should not be.is that correct ?so the picture in KamingHe git repo is for train mode because he used "use_global_state=true"

Comment: @sh.kh I suspect the opposite, `use_global_state=true` means using fixed weights for "deploy" phase